# suds to call SOAP over python

Tags: suds

i'm quite desperate...can't use suds in my code...I try this

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

import suds
url = "http://scsadx02:8080/lrs/webconnect/vpsx?trid=vpsx"
client = suds.client.Client(url)

Server = client.factory.create("ns0:string")
Serverin = client.factory.create("ns0:string")
UserID = client.factory.create("ns0:string")
Password = client.factory.create("ns0:string")
NewPassword = client.factory.create("ns0:string")
Server.value = 'SPLVSVK2'
Serverin.value = 'SPLVPSK2'
UserID.value = 'serviceudp'
Password.value = 'dpuecivres'
NewPassword.value = ''

#method I have to call  
#Suds ( https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ )  version: 0.4 GA  build: R699-20100913
#
#Service ( VPSXService ) tns="http://www.lrs.com"
#   Prefixes (2)
#      ns0 = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
#      ns1 = "http://www.lrs.com"
#   Ports (1):
#      (VPSXPort)
#         Methods (95):
#            Logoff(xs:string SessID, )
#            Logon(xs:string Server, xs:string UserID, xs:string Password, xs:string   NewPassword, )

client.service.Logon(Server, UserID, Password, NewPassword)
```

but I obtain this error...

```
[davide@archy PYTHON]$ ./testina.py 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "./testina.py", line 31, in <module>
    client.service.Logon(Server, UserID, Password, NewPassword)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 542, in __call__
    return client.invoke(args, kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 602, in invoke
    result = self.send(soapenv)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 637, in send
    reply = transport.send(request)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/transport/https.py", line 64, in send
    return  HttpTransport.send(self, request)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/transport/http.py", line 77, in send
    fp = self.u2open(u2request)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/transport/http.py", line 118, in u2open
    return url.open(u2request, timeout=tm)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1214, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1184, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
    urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
```

How I can solve???

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
C:\Python27>python -c "import urllib2; print urllib2.urlopen('http://scsadx02:8080/lrs/webconnect/vpsx?trid=vpsx').read()"
```

[and](http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-list/617037/) `import os; os.environ['http_proxy']=''` before importing the other modules.